# Entity Framework : two inner joins on the same table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following [database schema and relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qttQM.png)

What I'm trying to do is to select from the `ProductActiveIngredient` table with the known of `productId`, and I want to select every `ActiveIngredientOne`, `ActiveIngredientTwo`, `ActiveIngredientThree`, and `ActiveIngredientFour` from inner joining the `ActiveIngredient` table with `ProductActiveIngredient`.

Executing this query will return each `ActiveIngredientOne`, and `ActiveIngredientTwo` columns name:

```
select 
    a.ActiveIngredientOne, b.ActiveIngredientName, c.ActiveIngredientName
from
    ProductActiveIngredient a
inner join 
    ActiveIngredient b on a.ActiveIngredientOne = b.ActiveIngredientId
inner join 
    ActiveIngredient c on a.ActiveIngredientTwo = c.ActiveIngredientId
```

and the query result is:

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF4v1.png)

What I want to do is to make this query using Entity Framework.

I have the following models written in my solution:

```
public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ProductGuid { set; get; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cost")]
    public int Cost { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tax")]
    public int Tax { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Profit")]
    public int Profit { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Discount")]
    public int Discount { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public int Price { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Units")]
    public int Units { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Pack size")]
    public int PackSize { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { set; get; }
    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer id")]
    public int ManufacturerId { set; get; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { set; get; }
    public virtual ProductActiveIngredient ProductActiveIngredient { set; get; }
}

public class ProductActiveIngredient
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ProductActiveIngredientGuid { set; get; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductActiveIngredientId { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Active Ingredient 1")]
    public int ActiveIngredientOne { set; get; }
    //[Display(Name = "Active Ingredient 2")]
#nullable enable
    public int ActiveIngredientTwo { set; get; }
    public int ActiveIngredientThree { set; get; }
    public int ActiveIngredientFour { set; get; }
#nullable disable
    public int ProductId { set; get; }
    public int ForUser { set; get; }
    public virtual Product Product { set; get; }
    public virtual User User { set; get; }
    public virtual ActiveIngredient ActiveIngredient { set; get; }
}

public class ActiveIngredient
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string ActiveIngredientGuid { set; get; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ActiveIngredientId { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Active ingredient name")]
    public string ActiveIngredientName { set; get; }
    public virtual ProductActiveIngredient ProductActiveIngredient { set; get; }
}
```

and this is my db context relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(pai => pai.ProductActiveIngredient)
            .WithOne(p => p.Product)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductActiveIngredient>(p => p.ProductActiveIngredientId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveIngredient>()
            .HasOne(ai => ai.ProductActiveIngredient)
            .WithOne(aco => aco.ActiveIngredient)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductActiveIngredient>(a => a.ActiveIngredientOne);
modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveIngredient>()
            .HasOne(ai => ai.ProductActiveIngredient)
            .WithOne(aco => aco.ActiveIngredient)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductActiveIngredient>(a => a.ActiveIngredientTwo);
modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveIngredient>()
            .HasOne(ai => ai.ProductActiveIngredient)
            .WithOne(aco => aco.ActiveIngredient)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductActiveIngredient>(a => a.ActiveIngredientThree);
modelBuilder.Entity<ActiveIngredient>()
            .HasOne(ai => ai.ProductActiveIngredient)
            .WithOne(aco => aco.ActiveIngredient)
            .HasForeignKey<ProductActiveIngredient>(a => a.ActiveIngredientFour);
```

This LinQ query executes fine, and get the same result as the T-SQL query, but I need to do it in EF not in LinQ:

```
var s = from pac in _db.ProductActiveIngredient
    join ai in _db.ActiveIngredient on pac.ActiveIngredientOne equals ai.ActiveIngredientId
    join ai2 in _db.ActiveIngredient on pac.ActiveIngredientTwo equals ai2.ActiveIngredientId
    where pac.ProductId == productId
    select new
    {
        pac.ActiveIngredientOne,
        ai.ActiveIngredientName,
        pac.ActiveIngredientTwo,
        b2 = ai2.ActiveIngredientName
    };
```

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried changing your data model so that there is a many-to-many relation between `Product` and `Active Ingredient`?  This will eliminate the need for multiple joins.

Comment: Yes, It works fine now thanks.
What I did is added another three models in my ProductActiveIngredient class, and in ActiveIngredient class.
Then i used the .Include(x=>x.ProductActiveIngredientOne)
.ThenInclude(z=>z._ActiveIngredientOne).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: So you didn't understand @bbaird's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's done, Many thanks.
What I did is added another three virtual properties in my ProductActiveIngredient class, and in ActiveIngredient class.
Then i used the .Include(x=>x.ProductActiveIngredientOne)
.ThenInclude(z=>z._ActiveIngredientOne).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
and updated my db context as the properties above.